# .htaccess redirecting url with parametrs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how can I redirect this url:

```
http://www.indianastro.co.il/index.php?id=moon
```

to this:

```
http://www.indianastro.co.il/?p=217
```

via .htaccess

Comment: How is `moon` related to `217`?

Comment: New site build on wordpress. The old one was on custom system. Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

If there's no relation between the two identifiers (`moon` => `217`) you could use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html). Based on the example in the docs:

```
RewriteMap oldsite2wordpress txt:/etc/apache2/oldsite2wordpress.txt
RewriteRule ^index.php?id=(.*) /?p=${oldsite2wordpress:$1|NOTFOUND} [PT]
```

Then you define the mappings in `/etc/apache2/oldsite2wordpress.txt`

```
##
## oldsite2wordpress.txt - Maps old website IDs to WordPress IDs
##

moon 217
earth 87
sun 997
...
```